# how to close github issue using gitkraken glo?

Tags: git

I'm using GitKraken Glo. I want to close an issue on my github repo through GitKraken Glo board that is synced with my github repo. but I have no idea how to do that. Is that even possible?

Comment: This is exactly the purpose of GitKraken Glo Boards. [Delete the card that represents the issue, and you should be done!](https://support.gitkraken.com/glo/board-features/#remove-a-card)

Comment: thanks that helped. I'm using the local client. archiving the issue in GitKraken Glo closes it on github.

Comment: Post that as an answer and mark it as your solution please, @kerolloz

Comment: @varfirstName okay, I will.

Comment: @varfirstName why 

You can accept your own answer in 2 days

Comment: Oh yeah come back in two days. Much better for others to see this solution when googling their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They recently changed the way this is done. Now you'll need to close the card instead of archiving it. Does the same thing as archiving, which is to close the card in GitKraken and the issue in GitHub as well.

1. Left-click the 3 vertical dots in the upper right corner of the card.
2. Left-click the *Close* option.
3. Click *Close Card* to confirm you want to close both the card and the issue in GitHub.

Answer (score -1):

Archiving the card in GitKraken Glo client closes it on GitHub. (according to the git client)
@varfirstName comment has helped, thanks.